# Export Material Node Animations in GLTF (or other) exporter

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, three.js, gltf

I'm trying to do a best-as-I-can recreation of a blender scene in three.js simply from exporting it. So far the simplest / best way to start doing this is through the GTLF exporter / loader in THREE.js, which works great for the model and basic animations.

However, as seen in the [still in progress documentation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/master/docs/io_gltf2.rst),  it says:

> Animation glTF allows multiple animations per file, with animations
>   targeted to particular objects at time of export. To ensure that an
>   animation is included, either (a) make it the active Action on the
>   object, (b) create a single-strip NLA track, or (c) stash the action.
>
> Note
>
> Only certain types of animation are supported:
>
> Keyframe (translation, rotation, scale) Shape Keys Armatures /
>   Skinning
>
> Animation of other properties, like **lights or materials**, will
>   be ignored.

The question: how can I (or anyone else) implement a simple way to include animation of, lets say, the mapping node from cycleS? The main python source is [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/tree/master/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp), and the file that reads the materials is [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/master/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py), and the file that gets other animations is [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/master/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_animation_channel_target.py), it seems like the key part in the last one is:

```
def __gather_path(channels: typing.Tuple[bpy.types.FCurve],
                  blender_object: bpy.types.Object,
                  export_settings
                  ) -> str:
    target = channels[0].data_path.split('.')[-1]
    path = {
        "delta_location": "translation",
        "delta_rotation_euler": "rotation",
        "location": "translation",
        "rotation_axis_angle": "rotation",
        "rotation_euler": "rotation",
        "rotation_quaternion": "rotation",
        "scale": "scale",
        "value": "weights"
    }.get(target)

    if target is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot export an animation with {} target".format(target))

    return path
```

seemingly just adding the correct array value should do it maybe? But I don't know what to add, or what else to change to get this to work.

To clarify: I would  mainly just like to be able to export the animation for the Mapping texture node's position/scale/rotation (for now).

Comment: The unsupported animation types are current limitations of the glTF format, not the exporter, so unfortunately there's nothing you can embed in the file that will work, unless you're also planning to customize THREE.GLTFLoader (which, technically, you could do). I do expect UV mapping animation to be supported by glTF in the future.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Yes I was planning o n customizing the three loader, but how can I go about it? Mainly, how, with blender python, can I get the animation node data in some kind of list (that can be eventually converted to JSON)?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Blender Python API, hopefully someone else can answer how to access the animation node data. Once you have it, I expect the [glTF gitter channel](https://gitter.im/KhronosGroup/glTF) or [threejs forums](http://discourse.threejs.org/) could be helpful for the rest.